CUBE functions not updating after query refresh
I have several workbooks which use CUBE functions which reference the Data Model. Up until recently these always worked fine; now, however, after performing a full refresh of the queries which feed the Data Model, all formulas containing a CUBE function remain stuck, displaying #GETTING_DATA within the cell.
No VBA is incorporated and all queries within the workbook have Enable background refresh disabled.
The formulas can be forced to resolve by performing one or more (one is not always sufficient) full workbook recalculations, though this is clearly not ideal.
